# Hive SQL cast string as timestamp without losing the milliseconds

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have string data in the form `2020-10-21 12:49:27.090`

I want to cast it as a timestamp. When I do this:
`select cast(column_name as timestamp) as column_name from table_name`

all of the milliseconds are dropped, like this:
`2020-10-21 12:49:27`

I also tried this:
`select cast(date_format(column_name,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as timestamp) as column_name from table_name`

and the same problem persists, it drops the milliseconds.

How do I get it to convert strings to timestamps without losing the milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in Hive 2.3.6 on Qubole and on [demo.gethue.com](https://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor?editor=98378), works good:

```
select cast ('2020-10-21 12:49:27.090' as timestamp), 
       timestamp('2020-10-21 12:49:27.090')
```

Result:

```
2020-10-21 12:49:27.09    2020-10-21 12:49:27.09
```

And this

`cast(date_format('2020-10-21 12:49:27.090','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as timestamp)`

also works the same.

It seems like some problem with your client applpication or Hive version

Comment: Thanks, you're right, it was a problem with the software I was using to view the data. Thank you